# EF Core: How to generate C# code to populate dbcontext for unit test data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I want to unit test my code by using EF Core's *in-Memory database*. Therefore I populate the in memory database with the following code:

```
using (var context = new FahrzeugdatenDbContext(_options))
        {
            context.AntriebsArt.AddRange(new List<AntriebsArt>()
            {
                new AntriebsArt() { AntriebsArtId = 1, Kurzbezeichnung = "A"},
                new AntriebsArt() { AntriebsArtId = 2, Kurzbezeichnung = "F"},
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

it works fine but I don't want to create all records for all tables manually. Instead I would prefer to take some records from my live database. Is there any way or tool to generate such C# code or how would you tackle that issue? (I am guessing that I miss a keyword to find the right solution)

Comment: Most if not all unit tests should follow the three A's ([more here](https://medium.com/@pjbgf/title-testing-code-ocd-and-the-aaa-pattern-df453975ab80)) Arrange, Act, Assert. Arrange being where you would create the test data for the test that's about to run. At most I would make helper methods to quickly return a new object with some default values. In this case AntriebsArt

Comment: @MindSwipe thanks for hinting. I am well aware of that stuff. As I am on EF Core with DB first, I have no seed data in my code, but that is what I would need (and don't want to write by hand, neither do I want it to be randomly generated). hope that makes it clearer

Comment: You shouldn't need seed data, as the unit test should be creating it before it acts. Also, no AFAIK there is no tool/ automatic way to generate code to create random database entries, and creating one isn't necessary (at least IMO). [Obligatory XKCD](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/automation.png)

Comment: I know that the unit test should be creating it, but that's the point. I want to avoid writing that code. so i thought of "seeding" the dbcontext as a means to prepare for the unit test (that's basically what I do in my code example above).

Comment: @Jan checkout https://github.com/nbuilder/nbuilder or https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus